# JavaScript - Scrolling pixel array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am trying to implement a scrolling effect for a top-down shooter. Right now I have an array of stars that I am drawing to the screen. How can I make it appear as though the player is moving forward (scrolling the stars downward.) Here is what I have implemented so far:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    stars;

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    for(var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
            if(stars[y][x]) {
                context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

function update() {
    // TODO: game logic
}

window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';

    stars = new Array(canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
        stars[y] = new Array(canvas.width);

        for(var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
            if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) == 0) {
                stars[y][x] = true;
            } else {
                stars[y][x] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onresize();
setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: Example: http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/warpfield/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    stars.unshift(stars.pop()); // added

    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    for(var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
            if(stars[y][x]) {
                context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code moves bottom pixels to the top and lets other pixels slide down per frame.